# Unity3d How to create cuboctahedron?

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I want to create a [Cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron)

[image]

Like on this picture, can Unity3d create it like this?

```
GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify vertices using something like [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) API example.

However, I think the easiest and most efficient, performance wise, will be to use [Blender](http://www.blender.org) to create the model of the object.

Answer (score 1):

GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube) will create a cube and not a cuboctahedron. Still, you have a few options for getting the shape you want. As FunctionR said, you could make the shape in a modeling program, or create it through code in Unity. You could also follow some Blender tutorials and model it, but an even easier solution would be using a preexisting model. Try [this](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:543417/#files) model of a cuboctahedron and it should work just fine. Convert the downloaded .stl file to a .obj using [this](http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/) online converter, since Unity doesn't support models of the .stl type. Once you convert it to a .obj extension, you'll be able to use the model with Unity. Hope this helps you!